# Strange error in android studio, nothing similar online and no idea of the cause

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-maps, google-places-api

I am a new android developer, and every time I try to run the emulator to test my app I get the following error:

```
2020-08-05 15:08:30.625 8361-8361/com.example.tender E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.tender, PID: 8361
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzx;
    at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzw.zzaT(Unknown Source:0)
    at com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementContentProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source:4)
    at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:2388)
    at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:2358)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7239)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6780)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6697)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:237)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1913)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzx" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~7yQ-4JW3qh-QJVNZiOJdsA==/com.example.tender-hor871ahRQoy1oE54-r8dg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~7yQ-4JW3qh-QJVNZiOJdsA==/com.example.tender-hor871ahRQoy1oE54-r8dg==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system_ext/lib, /product/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:207)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzw.zzaT(Unknown Source:0) 
    at com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementContentProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source:4) 
    at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:2388) 
    at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:2358) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7239) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6780) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6697) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:237) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1913) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Any idea what could be causing this? I reverted my changes for the last two days to no avail, and searched google with nobody experiencing anything similar. If someone can make sense of the error, please help. For context, I recently added the Google Places SDK into my app, but this error occurs even when I comment out all the code related to that.

EDIT: As requested, here is my module-level build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.tender"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.2.0'
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't comment yet, but I'm assuming you're using R8 or Proguard when building, and it's obfuscating classes/fields/interfaces etc within the Google Places SDK that it tries to find at runtime through reflection.

Find the relevant rules for that library to include within your R8/Proguard rules file so they'll remain un-obfuscated when building.

**EDIT**: Also, are you using multidex with this application?

**EDIT2**: Worked with OP in the comments - issue seems to have stemmed from using the older general purpose bundled 'play-services' library in conjunction with the specific play-services libraries (like maps and places). Removing the bundled library fixed their issue.

Comment: I am using minimum sdk version 21, so multidex is built in. I had to change it to this after adding the places dependency, because it included more methods than could fit in a single dex file. And actually, I am not using R8 or Proguard to my knowledge, just multidex. Could this issue be caused by multidex?

Comment: Do you mind editing your post to include your module-level build.gradle (app/build.gradle)?

Comment: Okay, so `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services` is the old way of using play-service libraries. It brings in ALL other play-services libraries, like maps and places (which you're also bringing in directly). I'm surprised that even builds without a Duplicate Class error. Remove that general purpose dependency and only pull in the specific play-services libraries that you need (see here for a full list: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/packages). Do that first and see if it fixes your issue.

Comment: That seems to have fixed it, thanks for all the help

Comment: No problem, I'm glad to have helped. Feel free to accept this as the correct answer. I'll also update it so people in the future can no what the exact issue was.